# Расширение для оплаты юр. лицами (Wordpress, Woocommerce), существует ли подобное?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cms, интернет-магазин

Вообщем, существует некий интернет магазин, который работает на cms **Wordpress** в связке с **Woocommerce**. И мне бы хотелось добавить расширение к **Woocommerce**, которое бы добавляло дополнительный способ оплаты. Этот способ оплаты выставлял бы счет на безналичную оплату для юридических лиц и предоставлял им файл с данными(например: pdf).

Меня интересует, существует ли такое расширение и если да, то я бы хотел получить его название или ссылку.

P.s. я искал в интернете, но не нашел подходящего решения.

Answer (score 0):

Яндекс.Касса или CloudPayments - оба работают с юрлицами и дают свои плагины под вуку. А безналичный расчет есть из коробки в самом WooCommerce.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду чековые платежи? Если да то он дает недостаточно информации, а из настроек там есть только поля: наименование, описания и инструкция. Мне же нужно, чтобы при выборе безналичного расчета полей ввода в форме становилось больше, да и в идеале чтобы создавался pdf квитанция, которую можно было бы скачать и распечатать. Но похоже проще дополнительный шлюз сделать под это, потому что в интернете плагина подходящего не получилось найти :c

Comment: я жду вашего ответа :)

Comment: Генерировать PDF в обязанности платежных плагинов не входит, обычно есть отдельные плагины

Comment: я не вижу проблемы в генерации PDF файла. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как реализовать смену формы, при выборе моего способа оплаты.

Answer (score 0):

Много времени прошло, но как вариант - [Юридические и физические лица при оформлении заказа](https://opttour.ru/plugins/yur-ili-fiz-litso-pri-oformlenii/). Актуально и сейчас.

Все подробно расписано. Можете доработать и добавить код в файл functions.php своей дочерней темы WooCommerce.